# Do mail servers such as Yahoo, Windows Live Mail, Gmail block or trigger spam filters based on my IP address?

Tags: email, spam, email-validation, email-spam, spam-prevention

Does my IP address have any effect on mail getting marked as spam, or would it usually be triggered by the recipients server triggering spam based on the senders' server's IP address?

I've had a look at a blacklist check and can see the IP's provided to me by my ISP are blacklisted on SEM BLACK, SORBS DUHL, Spamhaus ZEN, would this have any effect on email deliver-ability?

Answer (score 0):

This absolutely has an effect on email deliverability. I previously worked on a bulk mailing system (newsletters), and we had to be extremely careful about what our clients sent out to prevent our system ips from being compromised.

You should indicate to your ISP that you are not happy with blacklisted IPs

Comment: If the IP's were to be compromised, which blacklists would you usually spot them on, and what did you do to solve this problem?

Comment: We had some issue initially with some of our clients sending unsolicited mail, so we were contacted by our ISP. From then, as a solution, we simply enforced extremely strict policies on our systems to prevent it being a problem in the future.

Comment: Any specific blacklists to watch out for, or i'm guessing all of them play a factor?

Comment: I imagine it would really depend on how your mail is routed across the  internet (If it passes a server with a blacklist, it may be automatically dropped, even if that server is not the intended destination). So to answer you directly, all of them between you and your client play a factor :)

Answer (score 0):

Most domains will block by IP address when filtering spammers. This means that whatever IP address is the one that touches the domain is the one that gets blacklisted if spam is suspected.

As deadlyDev said, definitely talk to your ISP - presuming that your actions aren't the ones that caused the blacklisting. If these are dedicated IP addresses, and if it's likely that your actions caused the problem, then maybe you should reconsider your practices.